# ReactJS className not being applied to component

Tags: reactjs

ReactJS newbie question. I have a searchbar component, as shown below, which includes two other components (LocationLookup & EmergencyService), both of which make use of "makeStyles" in their respective components and are styled without issue. However, I'm trying to apply a field separator to appear between each of the components within the searchbar component but for some reason the styles aren't being applied. Note that I've tried adding some additional CSS to change the font color and background color to the "fieldSeparator" class as well just to confirm that the issue isn't with the current before/after selectors. Doesn't matter what CSS I add to "fieldSeparator", it doesn't apply to those two components. FYI, the "searchBarContainer" CSS is applied to the searchbar container without issue. Not sure if this a props or state issue. Any tips on what I might be doing wrong would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

````
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles, withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

import LocationLookup from "./LocationLookup";
import EmergencyService from "./EmergencyService";


const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    searchBarContainer: {
        width: "calc(100% - 300px)",
        height: "44px",
        float: "left",
        flexGrow: "1",
        border: "1px solid #989586",
        borderRadius: "9999px",
        backgroundColor: "#fbfbf8",
        margin: "0"
    },
    fieldSeparator: {
        '&::after': {
            content: '""',
            borderRight: "1px solid #ccc9b3",
            position: "absolute",
            top: "10px",
            width: "1px",
            right: "0",
            height: "20px",
            bottom: "0"
        },
        '&::before': {
            content: '""',
            borderRight: "1px solid #ccc9b3",
            position: "absolute",
            top: "10px",
            width: "1px",
            right: "0",
            height: "20px",
            bottom: "0"
        },
        '&:hover': {
            '&::after': {
                display: "none"
            },
            '&::before': {
                display: "none"
            }
        },
    }
}));




export default function SearchBar() {

    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <div className={classes.searchBarContainer}>
            <LocationLookup className={classes.fieldSeparator} />
            <EmergencyService className={classes.fieldSeparator} />
        </div>
    );
}```
````

Comment: Are the LocationLookup and EmergencyService components using the className?
The className is applied on the outer div?

Answer (score 0):

**Why not using HTM/HTML/xml formats instead? The format look abit mix-up... thanks.. the structure are base Webbase or kernel Base? **

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have drilled down the props to your components like this:-

```
const LocationLookup = (props) => {
  return (
    <div {...props}>
      Hello
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your components `LocationLookup` and `EmergencyService` and make sure they are properly getting the props.